# Op-amp preamplifier input circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

This is an opamp-based preamplifier for a piezo ceramic transducer. I don't think the diodes on the Input Part are for protection. I think the voltage divider provides dc bias. But I don't understand exactly for what purpose the R3 resistor is there. I would be very grateful if someone could explain.

Comment: R3 provides a high resistance load to the piezo transducer. The R1, R3 and R4 junction should have a filter capacitor ( 2.2uF) to ground to kill power supply noise from being amplified by the opamp. The input protection diodes produce buzzing if in light from AC light bulbs so keep them covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the diodes are indeed there for protection.

R1 and R2 create a Thevenin equivalent voltage source of 1.5 V with an output impedance of 50 K ohms.  The circuit designer might have thought this was too low, possibly because you can minimize input bias current errors in opamp circuits if the DC impedance seen by both the inverting and non-inverting inputs are approximately equal.  The inverting input sees 500 K (two 1 M resistors in parallel).  R7 is not a factor in this because C6 is an open circuit at DC.

Another way to do the same thing is to increase R1 and R4 to 2 M each, and eliminate R3.

However, creating a bias voltage like this generates noise.  Often there is a noise filter capacitor from the bias voltage node to GND.  This would be in parallel with R4.  Depending on the components and circuit board layout, hanging a capacitor directly on the opamp input could cause the circuit to oscillate.  In this case, you then need R3 to "build out" the impedance seen by the non-inverting input.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Okay, what is the actual cause of the oscillation probability, and how does a resistor voltage divider network generate noise? If I put a cap like you're explaining. The R3 resistor is essential because of maintaining the input impedance. So, is it playing the role of damping in an oscillation scenario? If I'm not putting a cap then R3 is not essential. Do I understand right?

Comment: What oscillation are you talking about?  There is no mention of oscillation in your post.  Also, there is nothing in the circuit you posted that makes it prone to oscillation.  A large capacitive load on the opamp might cause it to oscillate, but you do not provide enough detail to discuss that.

Comment: Sorry Sir. I'm talking about that sentence you said to me " Depending on the components and circuit board layout, hanging a capacitor directly on the op amp input could cause the circuit to oscillate". I know you're say this for if I put a filter capacitor parallel through R4, already I am not understand why this causes oscillation. And beside this, I am not understand moreover why creating a bias voltage like this (voltage divider network) generates noise.

Comment: 1.  A filter capacitor in parallel with R4 will *not* cause oscillation.  2.  All resistors generate noise, and large value resistors generate more noise than low values.  Here is an explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

Comment: 3. If you add a capacitor from pin 1 to GND, this works with the output impedance of the opamp to form a phase shift network. Depending on the phase margin of the opamp, this added phase shift can be enough to cause the opamp circuit to oscillate at a high frequency.  Here is an app note on this topic:  https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an148fa.pdf?utm_medium_wp

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. All confusions more clear right now.